# Parallel for data structures

Tags: c#, multithreading, datatable, thread-safety, parallel.for

I am using a parallel.for to loop on a datatable. The value that changes in the loop is cirNumb, and with this value I query a datatable to populate an object of type `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. Then I call an instance of a struct and I have to pass to the struct this collection `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. Inside the struct I use the previous collection to populate a datatable but I found out that sometimes the result is correct, sometimes it is not and I suppose the error is in the assignation of the `IEnumerable<DataRow>` to the datatable.
Here some code:

```
Parallel.For(0, dtCir.Rows.Count, (i, state) =>
{     
    int cirNumb = Convert.ToInt32(dtCir.Rows[i]["no_of_circuits"]);
    IEnumerable<DataRow> dtConnectionSizeLoop = from dtConn in 
                                dtConnectionDatabase.AsEnumerable().AsParallel() 
                                where dtConn.Field<Int32>("no_of_circuits") == cirNumb

    CalculateDC calcDC;
    calcDC = new CalculateDC();
    calcDC.SetParameters(...,dtConnectionSizeLoop,...);
   //do some stuffs
}
```

The struct `SetParameters` method does some things and also assign to a datatable the object `IEnumerable<DataRow>`:

```
DataTable var_dtConnectionSize = dtConnectionSize.CopyToDataTable();
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Let's take a step back. Why are you considering the use of `Parallel` **at all**? How long does the code take to run if you use just plain loops (no `Parallel` or `AsParallel`)?

Comment: I use it because I have some intensive mathematical calculus inside the SetParameters method, in this way I can parallelize these operations. With plain loops the time is around 60 seconds.

Comment: Load data first, than calculate in parallel, then save data to the database

Answer (score 0):

The ADO.NET classes (`DataSet`, `Datatable` etc) are not thread-safe, so attempting to manipulate them from multiple threads in parallel without synchronization may easily corrupt their internal state. The incorrect results you observe may be caused by such a internal state corruption. The behavior of an object that has its internal state corrupted is undefined. It may throw exceptions, produce incorrect results, cause a deadlock etc. Nobody knows really.

To protect the objects from corruption you must introduce threading synchronization in your code ([locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)). Only one thread will be allowed to enter at a time, inside a protected block of code. This may create contention if the locks are hold for extended time spans, so it is important to release a lock as quickly as possible. Any code that doesn't need protection should be outside the protected region.

I could write some examples, but it's not obvious from the naming of your methods which method needs protection and which is not. It is possible that every line of your code manipulates thread-unsafe objects, in which case all should be protected, nullifying completely the benefits of parallelism in your case.